# Running parallel Tasks using SemaphoreSlim - confusion about performance

Tags: c#, performance, asynchronous, task, semaphore

I'm trying to send many http requests *async* and then collect the responses. To do this, I'm mainly using HtmlAgilityPack and SemaphoreSlim.

Unfortunately I'm facing performance issue which I'm struggling to solve.

When I add 1000 tasks to the list with SemaphoreSlim initCount = 15, I get all of them done in about 40 s.

When I add 2000 tasks, result goes linear and it takes about 80s to finish all of the tasks.

BUT when I start 2 console apps at the same time and put 1000 tasks in each, with Semaphore initCount=15 I get different result as it takes around 60 s to finish 1000 tasks from each app. That would mean I have just finished 2000 tasks in 60s.

How could I obtain this performance within usage of just 1 app, how to scale the performance up?

Please see code below:

Main:

```
using appParser.Services;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Diagnostics;

internal class Program
{
        static int j;
        static int k;
        static long sum=0;
        static HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            web.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36";
            
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            List<HtmlDocument> htmldocs = new();

            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            Console.WriteLine("Put request number");
            k = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Put initCount");
            j = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            var PerformanceTest = new PerfrormanceTestSemaphore(j);
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine($"InitCount: {j}");
            stopwatch.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            {
                tasks.Add(PerformanceTest.LoadDocs("https://m.olx.pl/elektronika/gry-konsole/q-xbox/?search%5Border%5D=created_at:desc", web));
            }
stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Tasks added in {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
            stopwatch.Restart();
                
            while (tasks.Count > 0)
            {
                stopwatch.Start();
                Task finished = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
                htmldocs.Add(((Task<HtmlDocument>)finished).Result);
                tasks.Remove(finished);
                stopwatch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine($"{tasks.Count} left, last finished in {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
                sum += stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                stopwatch.Restart();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine($"Tasks finished in {sum} ms");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------");
            await File.WriteAllTextAsync("html.txt", htmldocs[k-1].Text.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
```

PerfrormanceTestSemaphore Class:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace appParser.Services
{
    internal class PerfrormanceTestSemaphore
    {
        public int SemaphoreNum { get; set; }
        private SemaphoreSlim _mutex;
        
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new();
        public PerfrormanceTestSemaphore(int semaphoreNum)
        {
            SemaphoreNum = semaphoreNum;
            _mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(semaphoreNum);
        }

        public async Task<HtmlDocument> LoadDocs(string url, HtmlWeb web)
        {
            await _mutex.WaitAsync(cts.Token);
            try
            {
                string loadUrl = url + "&view=list/full_page=True";
                return await web.LoadFromWebAsync(url);
            }
            finally
            {
                _mutex.Release();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So your expectation is that you can increase the number of requests per second by spawning multiple processes, with each one of them spawning multiple tasks? Aren't all these requests sharing the same network bandwidth?

Comment: Yes, they share the same network bandwith but this not seem to be a problem. I have tested this program on my friend's PC and the result are quite the same.

Comment: Your 2-process test should be similar to running with double the `initialCount` in a single process with a single SemaphoreSlim.

Comment: So your expectation is that by increasing the number of processes, you should observe a linear increase in the total number of requests per second? For example 10 processes running on the same machine should do 10 times more work than a single process?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft this is what I thought at the beggining. But actually doubling the 'initialCount' slows the whole process down.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes, this is something I want to achieve. If I put, for example, 10 Tasks in the list to run in parallel and It takes 10% of machine CPU/RAM/network bandwith then I expect 100% of machine's resources being used while trying to process 100 Tasks.

Comment: How do you know what percentage of the network bandwidth is taken by a single process? There is no reference about this metric inside your question. I am asking because in case a single process takes almost 100% of the bandwidth, then the whole question is flawed because it is based on unrealistic expectations. If you have this metric, please include it in the question (by editing the question).

Answer (score 1):

`SemaphoreSlim` doesn't work across processes, which explains why your two application test is faster overall: there's less contention, by a factor of half. In other words your two tests don't test the same thing.

Edit: That said, if this is all you're doing, you don't need your semaphore at all. Simply create your tasks to download the link and use `Task.WhenAll` to collect the results. Let the framework figure out limits and work units.